# Connecting to Strava using R

Tags: r, api

Been messing with this all day. I'm just trying to pull down data from Strava to manipulate in R, but I can't figure this out. I'm not a programmer, but I've done this once connecting to a github file, but things aren't going my way.

Is this a basic mistake or am I missing some deeper principle that I just don't understand yet?

This is what I get when I try to run my code:

```
    x <- pullStravaData();
    > x
    <Token>
    <oauth_endpoint>
     request:       https://www.strava.com/oauth/authorize
     authorize:     http://localhost:1410
     access:        https://www.strava.com/oauth/token
     client_id:     3979
     response_type: code
    <oauth_app> strava
      key:    XX # I hid this, not sure if it matters
      secret: <hidden>
    <credentials> message, errors
```

AND this is my code:

```
pullStravaData <- function() {

    # because I think this is important
      library(httr);

      # not sure if this is relevant
      responseType = "code";
      clientId = 3979;

      # create app                
      clientSecret = trust_that_i_entered_this;
      accessToken = and_this_wrapped_in_quotes;
      myapp <- oauth_app("strava", accessToken, clientSecret);

      # get oauth credentials
      request <- "https://www.strava.com/oauth/authorize";
      authorize <- "http://localhost:1410";
      access <- "https://www.strava.com/oauth/token";
      strava_token <- oauth2.0_token(
          oauth_endpoint(request, authorize, access),
          myapp);

      data <- stravaPost(strava_token, clientId, clientSecret);

    }

    stravaPost <- function(token, clientId, clientSecret) {

      # I saw this happen somewhere else, but I'm pretty sure my script doesn't even get here
      stoken = config(token=token);
      req <- GET(sprintf("https://www.strava.com/api/v3/activities/%s",
          clientId), stoken, client_id = clientId, client_secret = clientSecret, code = token);
      stop_for_status(req); # not sure what this does
      content(req); # not sure what this does
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In order:

1. httr is the R http request library, so, including it via library(httr) is important, yes.
2. stop_for_status stops subsequent lines of code from running if the request has a worrying HTTP status - so, 404 (nothing found) or 403 (not authorised) for example.
3. content takes the actual content out of a HTTP response, and provides that, rather than returning the entire response.

You're not using any kind of explicit or implicit return() in the pullStravaData function. The result is it's not actually returning "data". Try turning:

```
 data <- stravaPost(strava_token, clientId, clientSecret);
```

into either:

```
 data <- stravaPost(strava_token, clientId, clientSecret);
 return(data)
```

or just:

```
 stravaPost(strava_token, clientId, clientSecret);
```

..and see what happens. While we're here, the semicolons are unnecessary, by the way.

I would highly advise that if you're going to be manually making these kinds of requests with R, you get an idea of how the language operates and what its rules are. [this](https://www.datacamp.com/courses/introduction-to-r) is pretty good, I hear.

Comment: I didn't know you don't need the semis. I have a decent understanding of the language, just not the api or http related functions.

After adding 'return(data)'
I still get the exact same response, I don't think explicitly returning the variable is the problem.

I think there is an authorization issue, but I'm not sure why (Error 401). Also, datacamp doesn't appear to cover anything this complicated, and the strava documentation is not written with R in mind.

Comment: Fair. Lacking an API key of my own the only thing I can suggest is that you dig into httr in some detail, rather than largely copying code, and look at how its OAuth setup works - the [package docs](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/httr/httr.pdf) are pretty good.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how accessing the strava API from `R` worked for me:

1. set up your strava API (check the [getting started guide](https://developers.strava.com/docs/getting-started/))
2. get your `Client ID` and `Secret` from https://www.strava.com/settings/api
3. use the following code in R:

```
library(httr)


strava_endpoint <- oauth_endpoint(
  request = NULL,
  authorize = "authorize", 
  access = "token",
  base_url = "https://www.strava.com/api/v3/oauth/"
  )

myapp <- oauth_app(
  "strava", 
  key = 11111,  # <- change this to your strava ID 
  secret = "mysecretkey" # <- change this to your client ID
)

mytok <- oauth2.0_token(
  endpoint = strava_endpoint, 
  app = myapp,
  scope = c("activity:read"), # somehow it does not work with multiple scopes
  cache = TRUE
)

resp <- GET("https://www.strava.com/api/v3/athlete", config(token = mytok))

jsonlite::fromJSON(rawToChar(resp$content))
```

feel free to wrap this into a function!